# Samba Secondary DC,No DNS Forwarding

Tags: domain-name-system, samba, internal-dns, samba4

I'm new to Linux and testing Samba AD DC. 
I've set up 2 DCs.
DC1 is able to resolve google.com, DC2 is not.

> nslookup google.com 192.168.0.100 
>   Server:         192.168.0.100 
>   Address:        192.168.0.100#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer: 
>   Name:   google.com 
>   Address: 172.217.20.110

On DC2 however I get the following error

> nslookup google.com 192.168.0.104 
>   Server:         192.168.0.104 
>   Address:        192.168.0.104#53
>
> ** server can't find google.com: NXDOMAIN

DC1 has the smb.conf file where dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8 
DC2 doesn't seem to have this smb.conf file. 
Where does the forwarder need to be specified?

The guide I've followed is: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Joining_a_Samba_DC_to_an_Existing_Active_Directory

However, it says here that DNS Transfers are not possible. 
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Internal_DNS_Back_End

Is there any other way to make DC2 also resolve DNS requests by using SAMBA_INTERNAL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
You have to add "dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8" in /usr/local/samba/etc/smb.conf